# Should I be concerned about duplicate entries in a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've come across some PHP code which is generating a query like the below (I've ommited the WHERE clause for clarity)

```
SELECT user.id FROM users 
JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY users.id, users.id
```

Now, it appears to work but I'm weary of the duplicates in GROUP BY. I'm aware that `GROUP BY users.id, users.id` doesn't make sense and that I can use `SELECT distinct(user.id)` without grouping.
I'm wondering if it's going to cause problems or if it will always just execute as

```
SELECT user.id FROM users 
JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Yeah, that does not make sense at all. Remove that second `user.id`. Since the data is always the same (it is the same column) the group won't change. probably a Copy&Paste error.

Comment: It doesn't make sense but I'm fairly certain in sql-server at least that it does no harm.

Comment: In the absence of aggregating functions (and I'm assuming that none were removed for clarity), the use of a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate. Perhaps you were thinking of the DISTINCT operator.

Comment: @Strawberry: Why is it inappropriate?

Comment: @Strawberry I assume this query is simplified. Also presumably grouping by all columns and using DISTINCT are the same.

Comment: Because nothing is being aggregated.

Comment: So there's a perfectly good operator for selecting DISTINCT results

Comment: @Strawberry there are many more columns being selected in the real example (none from table2, so aggregates are not used) so DISTINCT would not be replacement

Comment: Guess I need to read up on DISTINCT then..

Comment: @juergend I'm aware it doesn't make sense, the statement is generated like this. I've edited my question to be clearer, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query (with the initial "S" added):

```
SELECT user.id
FROM users JOIN
     table2
     ON table2.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY user.id, user.id;
```

This query is not syntactically correct.  You have a table named `users`, which is never referenced, and an alias `user` which is never defined.  If this code is being generated, then there is a bigger error than duplicates in the `group by` clause.

If the tables are set up correctly, then `table2.user_id` should always be a valid id in the `users` table.  If so, then the following is a much simpler version of the query:

```
SELECT distinct t.user_id as id
FROM table2 t;
```

The difference between this and:

```
SELECT t.user_id as id
FROM table2 t
GROUP BY t.user_id;
```

is very minor (they should produce the same execution plans).  However, because MySQL supports "hidden columns" -- that is, columns in the `select` clause that are not aggregated and not in the `group by` clause -- there are some situations where the `distinct` and `group by` are not identical.  This does not apply to other databases.  And, I would consider these situations to be poorly formed SQL, but they do exist.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT distinct t.user_id as id, t.value
FROM table2 t;
```

Is not necessarily the same as:

```
SELECT t.user_id as id, t.value
FROM table2 t
GROUP BY t.user_id;
```

Although both are syntactically correct MySQL statements.

Comment: I've edited my question, user/users was mixed in my question but not in the actual code

Comment: Gordon, are you saying that both of your second examples are poorly formed - or only the DISTINCT example?

Comment: Could you clarify which situations you refer to with this comment :` And, I would consider these situations to be poorly formed SQL` and explain why they are poorly formed?

Comment: @AgRizzo . . . I consider the use of hidden columns to be poorly formed SQL, with the possible of exception of where they conform to the SQL Standard for using this construct.  In an aggregation query, fields should be either included in the `group by` clause, derived from such fields directly, or be the arguments to aggregation functions.